Can't connect to the server (after time goes by)
I am finding a lot that if I leave the browser on one of my pages, after a bit of time goes by it dulls the entire page and at the top it says "Can't connect to the server" and gives me a reload link.
Am I doing something wrong here? Or does this happen with Blazor Interactive Server Mode pages?
These are pages without a form, but they are populated with data from the DB.

.Net9 may partially solve this issue https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-9.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0#improved-server-side-reconnection-experience
